# I want output as group of different table using SQL Group By clause

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I want output as group of different table using SQL Group By clause , I have Different Table but same internal structure. My Table Name Is Location name having same data

Comment: Show us the table structures, some sample data, and what you wish to see at the end. Also what have you tried.

Comment: Also, many of us would greatly appreciate a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT t1.TimeStamp, t2.State, t1.OtherData
FROM Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 
    on t1.SpecialNumber = t2.SpecialNumber
inner join (SELECT MAX(time stamp) maxts, state
            FROM table1 inner join table2
            ON table1.specialnumber = table2.specialnumber
            GROUP BY state) t3
    on t2.State = t3.State and t1.TimeStamp = t3.maxts
```

Comment: table name Loc1,Loc2 and it has Data field are startamount , Spendamount , endamount .